# Searching for a C# graph framework with that you can draw AND manipulate graphs by mouse

Tags: c#, frameworks, graph, drag-and-drop, draw

As the title suggests, i am searching for a c# framework to draw graphs.

It is important to me, that you manipulate the graph structure by using the mouse.
You should be able to select and nodes and connections and interact with them.
For example you could draw your own graphs from scratch.

The framework should provide the basic functions to create nodes and connections between them, but should also be that flexibel to implement your own stuff. for that reason i really prefer open source.

Also cross-plattform support would be really nice, but that is no must.
Also 3d would be nice, but 2d will do it too.

I first thought about implementing an own graph engine via opengl, but that was a bit too much work for my purpose ;)

Comment: I would say that implementing a graph in 2D should be easy enough as to be something DIY.

Comment: @SoMoS Visual layout algorithms can be quite complex.

Comment: and my point is the interaction thing! thats not that simple ;)

Comment: Is it for Web, forms, silverlight, WPF?

Comment: Desktop application. Primary target: Windows. So, Forms.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to have a look at the [oxyplot](http://oxyplot.org/) project.

The project is well documented and the online examples browser have a source which fits with your needs

See **Mouse Events** section and ''LineSeries and PlotModel MouseDown event''